# Spring cloud kafka : RecordTooLargeException for producer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have been looking around about this for a bit now and have come across a number of different articles and posts about this. From what i gather I need to increase the 'max.request.size' from the default 1000000.

I can see a bunch of properties on the [apache kafka website](http://kafka.apache.org/082/documentation.html#producerconfigs), but these look like properties in a `.properties` file but I am using a `.yml` for my properties. I cannot seem to find anywhere what has examples for this

I have tried a number of different ways (please see below for just a few. Has anyone come across articles or post on how to set these in .`yml` files or know how this should be done?

```
spring:  
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        bindings:           
          output:
            producer:
              max:
                request:
                  size: 5000000 


spring:  
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:           
          max:
            request:
              size: 5000000
```

Comment: The broker will still reject large messages if you increase only the producer properties. You need to edit the value on the serverside

Comment: I am aware of this and I know the values that need to be set for this as well but want to tackle on thing at a time. If I find how to set this then on the consumer side Im hoping its going to be similar